# counter ++ vs counter = counter+1;

Tags: javascript, increment, operator-keyword

```
var counter = 0;
var increment = function(){
    return counter++;
    // return counter=counter+1;
}

console.log(increment());
```

Why does **counter ++;** returns 0 but **counter = counter +1;** returns 1?

Answer (score 3):

The post-fix increment operator returns *the current value* for evaluation and *then* increments it, so the value change is noticeable when it is referenced for the second time.

So when the `return` statement is executed, the value has not *yet* been incremented. You can cross-check by doing the following:

```
console.log(counter++); // 0
console.log(counter); // 1
return counter; // obviously 1
```

Try the pre-fix operator which increments and *then* returns the *incremented* value to be evaluated.

```
return ++counter; // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called [prefix (`++x`) vs postfix (`x++`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_(.2B.2B)) and the only difference is really the order of operations:

```
counter;
```

evaluates to a value. (0)

```
counter++;
```

evaluates to a value (0), performs a calculation (0 -> 1) and modifies a variable (`counter` -> 1).

```
++counter;
```

performs a calculation (0 + 1), modifies a variable (`counter` -> 1) and evaluates to a value (1).

Answer (score 1):

var counter = 0;

```
var increment = function(){
// now counter is 0 and after return it increment it's value to 1
// return 0 then 0+1=1;
    return counter++;
// calculate like math, counter = 0+1 then counter = 1, now return 1;
    // return counter=counter+1;
}

console.log(increment());
```

In first scenario,

```
return counter++;
```

This statement is postfix, and evaluates like

```
return 0; and then 0+1=1
```

In second scenario,

```
return counter=counter+1;
```

Calculate like math,

```
return counter = 0+1 then,
return counter = 1, 
return 1;
```